Disabled copilot on Win11 23H2 and now I can't get it back
I disabled desktop Co-Pilot in Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2 using both of XDA's suggested methods - setting a group policy and setting a registry key. I have undone both of those disablements by setting the Group Policy back to "not configured" and have set the HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\windowscopilot key to 0. After reboot, CoPilot still is gone and Win+c does nothing. I even used vivetool to try to re-enable the features, but no luck. Is there something I'm missing?
Edit: when trying to manually invoke the sidebar with microsoft-edge:///?ux=copilot&tcp=1&source=taskbar it just opens Edge with a blank page.
Edit 2: Vivetool args: /enable /id:44774629,44776738,44850061,42105254,41655236
Edit 3: I installed the "copilot" app from the MS store but Win+C still doesn't work

There are three methods described on that website. So which two methods did you use? Where did you get the Vivetool  ids?

I used the group policy and the registry entry. The vivetool commands are on dozens of pages, but I specifically used this page: https://mspoweruser.com/how-to-enable-windows-copilot-via-vivetool/

Those Vivetool ids are not applicable in November 2024. They were applicable late 2023.  Have you tried to create a new Edge user profile?

Do you have more recent IDs I can try? this is the latest set I could find. I deleted and re-created my Edge profile but it didn't help

Using the ViveTool GUI, it shows that the TaskbarCopilot, TaskbarCopilot_Settings, and systrayCopilotNi features are enabled

"Do you have more recent IDs I can try?" - I don't because it was only necessary to use Vivetool from before CoPilot became a feature of Windows in 2023.

Give this a try: Go into Settings > Apps > Installed Apps > Scroll down and look for Microsoft Copilot app > Click on the three-dot menu beside Microsoft Copilot and select Advanced options > click Repair.

the only entry for copilot was simply "copilot" that I installed today. There isn't a separate "Microsoft Copilot". I repaired the one I found and it didn't change anything. in fact, if I open this new "copilot" app it's just an electron-like edge window with a copilot interface, it can't access local resources

Reddit posts and various blogs indicate that the core of desktop copilot is the "Microsoft.Windows.AI.Copilot.Provider" package, which I do not seem to have and cannot find out how to reinstall.

WinAero has an option to remove Copilot. You may be able to use it to restore it as well. I have used WinAero and it is safe to use, but haven't tested if it will restore Copilot.

You may also want to install the Microsoft Copilot App from the store.
